# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /var/www/article.php on line 77

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know this has been asked before, but I all the answers I went through didn't really help.
So this should output the content of a topic, however it tells me

> Notice: Undefined variable: articles in /var/www/article.php on line
>   77
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/article.php on line 77

```
        if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $setid = $_GET['id'];       
        $articles = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM front_articles WHERE article_id=:article_id');
        $articles->bindParam(':article_id', $setid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $articles->execute();
}       
        while($article = $articles->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        echo $article->article_content;
}
```

EDIT: the thing is that I have the same code for user stats, and it works just fine

```
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $setid = $_GET['id'];       
        $user_stats = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID=:ID');
        $user_stats->bindParam(':ID', $setid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $user_stats->execute();
        }
    while($stats = $user_stats->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
   ?>
   <div id="stats"> 
    <?php   
    echo 'Username: '.$stats->username.'<br>'.
          'e-mail: '.$stats->email.'<br>'.
          'Posts: '.$stats->post_count.'<br>'.
          'Member Since: '.$stats->created.'<br>'.
          'Age: '.$stats->age.'<br>'.
          'Location: '.$stats->location.'<br>'.
          'Name: '.$stats->name.'<br>';
   ?>   
    </div>  
<?php   
    }
?>
```

Comment: This simply means that $articles is not an object. It has not been defined in the code before.

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that `$articles` isn't an object.  So you never defined it.  Note that you try to define it, but inside of a conditional statement only.  So, clearly, that conditional code block isn't being executed.

In short, `if(isset($_GET['id'])){` is probably evaluating to `false` and not executing your PDO code.

Currently your code assumes that `$articles` will always have a value.  Which means one of two things is true:

1. The assumption is wrong and you should check if `$articles` has a value before trying to use it.
2. The assumption is correct and the `if` conditional isn't needed (since it should always be `true`) and can be removed entirely.

It's *probably* the case that the assumption is wrong.

Comment: @Kris: Clearly there's some difference between the two.  If not in the code then in the context in which the code runs.  (That is, perhaps when the other code runs `$_GET['id']` is set.)

Comment: @Kris: And what's the difference in which these two code blocks are executed?  Are they on the same page, or different pages?  Is `$_GET['id']` set in both instances?  What is the value of `$_GET['id']` in each instance?

Comment: no the articles one is on articles.php and users one is on user.php and $_GET['id'] is set in both instances. it's 8 in the articles.php and 5 in user.php, however both of those IDs exist in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Articles is not an object. You can put it in a if statement to skip when you don't get any result from DB.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $setid = $_GET['id'];       
        $articles = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM front_articles WHERE article_id=:article_id');
        $articles->bindParam(':article_id', $setid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $articles->execute();
}       

        if (isset($articles)) {
        while($article = $articles->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        echo $article->article_content;
        } else {
        echo 'No result found. Err: Article is not an object';
        }
}
```